# how make notification scrollable as fb on css

Tags: html, css

[image]   i want to make notifications (li) scrollable when i put the li of notification in one div class="notification-body" it doesn't give me the result i want as bellow on the picture.

```
<li ng-if="vm.logged">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn-noti" id="dropdownNoti" ng-click="vm.showDropdown($event)">
          <span class="fa fa-bell-o"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu notification-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownNoti">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" style="border-bottom: #655771;border-bottom-style: double;">
            <h5 class="notification-title"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i> Notifications</h5>
            <a class="mark-all" ng-click="vm.markAllRead()">Mark all as read</a>
          </div>
          <div class="notification-body">
            <li ng-if="!vm.notifications.length"><a>You have no new notification yet.</a></li>
            <li class="notification-type"  ng-repeat="notification in vm.notifications" ng-style="{'background-color': notification.unread==false? 'white' : '#f5f5f5'}" style="border-bottom-style: ridge;">
              <a ui-sref="profile({id: post.user.id})">{{notification.description}}
                <h6><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> {{vm.timeOf(notification)}}</h6>
              </a>
              <a class="mark-as btn btn-default " ng-click="vm.markAsRead(notification)" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-content="as read" ng-class="{'add-white' : notification.unread==true }" ></a>
            </li>

          </div>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
```

Comment: when i try to put li notifications on a dive to give it ad height and overflow scroll it doesn't work

Comment: can you post a working example/fiddle?

Comment: @Sahil Dhir check the edit above plz :)

Comment: you can give class dropdown some height and overflow:scroll..

Comment: i did it , this will not solve the width problem i still as the pic above and when i give the class drop down > overflow:scroll with height :300px this makes the whole notification i just want the part of class=notification-body to be scrollable !   
@Sahil Dhir

Comment: Check this example - http://www.bootply.com/tB4UXeU5pi  for help  +  give your notification-body height + overflow

Answer (score 1):

By setting `Height` and `Width` property of `not-body` style you can achive it.

`<div class="not-body" style="height:200px; width:100px; overflow:scroll;">`

Try doing it. I think it'll work as you want.

Comment: i made these things but my problem isn't that plz check the edit above :)